# Broadcast to different channel Phoenix 1.1.6

Tags: sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm trying to broadcast to a different channel in my app but I can not get it to work. Also I trying to write a test but I'm not sure how.

From what I can gather I succeed in broadcasting the message from the notification_channel but it's not received in chat_channel.

Notification should send to chat.

**notification_channel.ex**

```
  def handle_in("new:group:recommendation", msg, socket) do
    payload = %{
        message: msg["message"],
        url: msg["url"],
        title: msg["title"],
        user_name: get_name_of_user(socket.assigns.user_grapqhl_id),
        user_grapqhl_id: socket.assigns.user_grapqhl_id
    }

    IO.puts "incomming"
    IO.inspect msg
    Enum.map(msg["groups"], fn(x) ->
        App.Endpoint.broadcast_from! self(), "chat:"<>x,
            "new:recommendation", payload
        end)
    {:reply, :ok, socket}

  end
```

**chat_channel.ex**

```
 def handle_in("new:recommendation", msg, socket) do
      IO.puts "i am a recommendation !"
      IO.inspect msg
      chat_msg = %{
         "creator_id" => msg["user_grapqhl_id"],
         "text" => msg["message"],
         "creator_name" => msg["user_name"]
      }

     broadcast! socket, "new:msg", create_chat_msg(chat_msg,socket)
     {:reply, :ok, socket}
  end
```

**test**

```
  test "do we send a new:recommendation to chat ?", %{guardian_token: guardian_token} do
      nils_base_64 = Base.encode64("user:nils")

      {:ok, socket} = connect(UserSocket, %{})
      {:ok, _, socket1} = subscribe_and_join(socket, "notifications:"<>nils_base_64, %{"guardian_token" => guardian_token})
      {:ok, _, socket} = subscribe_and_join(socket1, "chat:Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw==", %{"guardian_token" => guardian_token})

      payload = %{
          "message" => "look at this cool thing!",
          "url" => "link to stuff",
          "title" => "AWESOME EVENT",
          "groups" => ["Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw==", "Y2hhdDpwdWJsaWM="]
      }

      reply = %{message: "look at this cool thing!", title: "AWESOME EVENT", url: "link to stuff", user_grapqhl_id: nils_base_64, user_name: "Nils Eriksson"}

      ref = push socket1, "new:group:recommendation", payload
      assert_reply ref, :ok
      assert_broadcast "new:recommendation", ^reply
  end
```

This test passes and i can get it to fail by changing the `reply`
or commenting out the broadcast. I can not get it to fail by changing the `handle_in` to receive `fail:please` in `chat_channel`. 
That is something that it would complain on if i would send change this 
`ref = push socket1, "new:group:recommendation", payload` 
to `ref = push socket, "new:group:recommendation", payload` not supprising in that case.

This is what is on the wire.

```
     Process mailbox:
   %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "init:msgs", payload: %{messages: []}, ref: nil, topic: "chat:Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw=="}
   %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "new:recommendation", payload: %{message: "look at this cool thing!", title: "AWESOME EVENTs", url: "link to stuff", user_grapqhl_id: "dXNlcjpuaWxz", user_name: "Nils Eriksson"}, topic: "chat:Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw=="}
   %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "new:recommendation", payload: %{message: "look at this cool thing!", title: "AWESOME EVENTs", url: "link to stuff", user_grapqhl_id: "dXNlcjpuaWxz", user_name: "Nils Eriksson"}, ref: nil, topic: "chat:Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw=="}
```

I use channel authentication since the elm package i use does not support authentication on socket level yet. so this is what it looks like in `chat`

```
  def join("chat:" <> chat_id, %{"guardian_token" => token}, socket) do
  IO.puts chat_id
  case sign_in(socket, token) do
     {:ok, authed_socket, _guardian_params} ->
         Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
         send(self, {:after_join})
         [_type, node_chat_id] = Node.from_global_id(chat_id)
         {:ok, assign(authed_socket, :chat_id, node_chat_id)}
     {:error, reason} ->
         IO.puts "Can't join channel cuz: " <> reason
       # handle error TODO
   end
```

end

Answer (score 6):

Since you use `broadcast_from/4` from your `Endpoint`.You should use `handle_info/2` in your `chat_channel`:

```
alias Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast
  ...

def handle_info(%Broadcast{topic: _, event: ev, payload: payload}, socket) do
    IO.puts ev
    IO.inspect payload
    # do something with ev and payload( push or broadcast)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Or you can listen that event from your client:

```
chatChannel.on("new:recommendation", resp => {
   // doSomething with response
}
```

**Edit:**

Let's explain a bit about how the `channel` and `PubSub` system work.

When you want to broadcast or push an event with payload.First it will send to the `PubSub` system and then the `PubSub` system will send it to all the subscriber process (`channel`) with the topic that `channel` registered itself with the `PubSub` system.

And when you use `Endpoint.broadcast_from/4` to broadcast an event from your server.The `PubSub` system will receive an event with payload and broadcast that event to the topic that channel registered.

The channel will trigger `handle_out` callback and push the message to the client.
So in your `chat_channel` you don't need to `handle_in` "new:recommendation" event.Your client just need to listen to that event.

```
chatChannel.on("new:recommendation", resp => {
   // do something with response
}
```

And let me rewrite your test:

```
setup do
    nils_base_64 = Base.encode64("user:nils")
    {:ok, socket} = connect(UserSocket, %{})
    {:ok, _, socket} = subscribe_and_join(socket, "notifications:"<>nils_base_64, %{"guardian_token" => guardian_token})
    {:ok, socket: socket}
  end


test "do we send a new:recommendation to chat ?", %{socket: socket} do
      MyApp.Endpoint.subscribe("chat:Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw==")

      payload = %{
          "message" => "look at this cool thing!",
          "url" => "link to stuff",
          "title" => "AWESOME EVENT",
          "groups" => ["Y2hhdDpjaGF0Mw==", "Y2hhdDpwdWJsaWM="]
      }



      reply = %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{message: "look at this cool thing!",
              title: "AWESOME EVENT",
              url: "link to stuff",
              user_grapqhl_id: nils_base_64,
              user_name: "Nils Eriksson"}

      ref = push socket, "new:group:recommendation", payload
      assert_reply ref, :ok
      assert_receive ^reply
  end
```

By `subscribe` to the topic that you want to listen you can make sure that your channel is received the message with `assert_receive`.
That is the way to test `broadcast` to a different channel.

Give it a try and tell me.The test will pass.

Comment: Does it matter that i have channel auth ? nothing changed when i tried this. 
I have managed to subscribe to external channels, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: oh your test's already passed.So what is the problem? i thought you can't broadcast to different channel?

Comment: Yes they pass but they don't test if they get received in the chat channel. 
The message is broadcasted but not picked up.

Comment: I edited the answer.You can give it a try and tell me

Comment: Tnx alot, but feels like i missed the point what I'm trying to do. 
I have a notifications channel, when that get certain notifications i want to send a msg to the chat channel and say "Hey i just got a new:group:recommendation take that and convert that into a chat:msg"

i don't want to send new:group:recommendation to the client, just to another channel where i can transform it into a chat msg.

Answer (score 1):

Use `App.Endpoint.broadcast topic, event, payload` with the topic of your chat channel. It should work.